# AxiosError in React js

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, axios

[image]

POST api/v1/country_list 400 (Bad Request)
This error will show when using axios in react js

```js
const handleLogin =(e) =>{
    axios.post('api/v1/country_list').then(result=>{
        console.log(result);
    }).catch(error =>{
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Comment: Is that the correct URL? does not need to start with / like `/api/v1/country_list`

Comment: No its just for a view.. not original.. actually original api is there

Comment: Can you open that AxiosError? Does it say some information, maybe some message?

Comment: message
: 
"Request failed with status code 400"
name
: 
"AxiosError"

Comment: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49509:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48204:66)"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Error